# Need to extract the contents of two html classes with same name

Tags: html, python-3.x

I want to extract the contents of the following html code

```
<div class="card__content">
<div class="card__title">
Sajjad Haider Khan
<svg class="icon link__icon" height="10" width="10">
<use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right">
</use>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="card__position">
Student,
<span class="card__text">
Computer Science Engineering (CSE)
</span>
</div>
<div class="card__position">
<span class="card__text">
Career Interests:
</span>
Computer Science; Python; Machine Learning
</div>
</div>
```

I need all the contents of both the card__position classes. In the second card__position class, there is a double quoted text after the span class closing. I want to extract that text as well.

I am able to extract only the card__title and the contents of only first card__position class with the following code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

url = '<url>'

uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card__content"})

container = containers[0]

title = container.findAll("div", {"class": "card__title"})
#print(name[0].text)

position = container.findAll("div", {"class": "card__position"})
#print(position[0].text)
```

However, I want to print the results as in the following manner:

```
Sajjad Haider Khan
Student
Computer Science Engineering (CSE)
Career Interests: Computer Science; Python; Machine Learning
```

Answer (score 0):

The code has the correct approach. However I'd recommend separating code into fetching html & scraping results. The scrape results code should return results in some sort of response object. My example below uses `NamedTupple` (for ease of use).

`find_all()` should be used if you wish to find more than one html element. Otherwise use `find()` to get the first item. Also there is a slight typo of findAll().

Also this question only provides a snippet of html content. This makes it difficult to make assumptions. However I assume the html always contains 2 divs with class card__position. I use `assert` to throw an exception if this is not true.

Anyway below is an example, which achieves the desired output:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ExtractResponse = namedtuple('ExtractResponse', ['Name', 'Role', 'Course', 'MiscInfoTitle', 'MiscInfoDetails']) # This is used to store date frome extract. Not too sure on correct namings

html = '''<div class="card__content">
<div class="card__title">
Sajjad Haider Khan
<svg class="icon link__icon" height="10" width="10">
<use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right">
</use>
</svg>
</div>
<div class="card__position">
Student,
<span class="card__text">
Computer Science Engineering (CSE)
</span>
</div>
<div class="card__position">
<span class="card__text">
Career Interests:
</span>
Computer Science; Python; Machine Learning
</div>
</div>'''

def extract(soup):
    card_container_soup = soup.find("div", {"class": "card__content"}) # use find() if you know there is 1 instance (e.g <div class="card__content">)
    title_soup = card_container_soup.find("div", {"class": "card__title"})

    card_positions_soup = card_container_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card__position"})
    assert len(card_positions_soup) == 2 # Validate that there are always 2 card__position. If theres is not, the scrape results will be wrong.
    
    # This code assumes the first card__position contains course data and the second contains intrest
    card_text_1_soup = card_positions_soup[0].find('span', {'class': 'card__text'})
    card_text_1 = card_text_1_soup.text.strip()
    card_text_1_soup.extract() # remove card text. This is so that the non span text can be scraped.

    card_text_2_soup = card_positions_soup[1].find('span', {'class': 'card__text'})
    card_text_2 = card_text_2_soup.text.strip()
    card_text_2_soup.extract()

    response = ExtractResponse(title_soup.text.strip(), card_positions_soup[0].text.strip().replace(',', ''), card_text_1, card_text_2, card_positions_soup[1].text.strip())
    return response

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
results = extract(soup)

print(results.Name)
print(results.Role)
print(results.Course)
print(f"{results.MiscInfoTitle} {results.MiscInfoDetails}")
```

**Output:**

```
Sajjad Haider Khan
Student
Computer Science Engineering (CSE)
Career Interests: Computer Science; Python; Machine Learning
```